# Diagram Software

Tags: software-recommendation

I study computing on an advanced level and I need a program that will make it easier to create flowcharts and other diagrams efficiently. I don't need too many features; I just want something that works! I'm aware that there are many website that do exactly what I need but most of the times when I need to draw diagrams I don't have access to the internet

Comment: an example of a site that does diagrams is http://www.diagram.ly/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two that I know of:

1. [Shapes](http://shapesapp.com/) - Cheap ($5) with a decent array of tools
2. [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) - Expensive, but it can do pretty much anything, including reading Vizio files (Pro version)

Comment: Decided to go with Shapes since I just need to do a couple of flowcharts for a project. Thx x x x

Answer (score 3):

It isn't cheap, but [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) from OmniGroup is truly outstanding. Student pricing is available, and substantially less expensive than full retail price. ($60 vs $100)

Comment: OmniGraffle is by far the best option for the Mac today. I can highly recommend it as I use it to diagram complex systems daily.

Answer (score 3):

Try Graphviz(http://www.graphviz.org/).  It is free, powerful, and easy to learn.  You don't need draw anything, just write a piece of code, and the program will generate a fig for you.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org) office suite (and its forked cousin, [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org)) is completely free, and includes a drawing application that is actually fairly useable for creating diagrams and flowcharts at the simpler end of the scale.